# Highcharts is hiding xAxis range because there are no values on yAxis

Tags: highcharts

I set the minimum and maximum values of x axis using 
`$('#chart').highcharts().xAxis[0].setExtremes(xAxis.min,xAxis.max,true,false);`

However if I don't have data for the initial period (from xAxis.min), highcharts will not start from xAxis.min, however it will start from the first data point.

How do I make highcharts to show xAxis from the xAxis.min even if there may not be a corresponding Y value at that time.

In the attached screenshot, I had set the xAxis.min to 1'st Dec however since my data started from 6'th dec, it has hidden that xAxis range from 1'st Dec to 6'th dec.

Any help is appreciated.

[image: highcharts hiding xAxis range]

Comment: jsFiddle example would be great. If you are using Highstock, set `axis.ordinal = false` or add null data point for that min x-value.

Comment: I am not using `HighStock`. I will try to come up with jsFiddle however not sure if I will be able to repeat the problem.

Comment: If you can't recreate issue on jsFiddle, that would mean you have old version for Highcharts. Try 3.0.7

Comment: Apparently what I did was, I just imported data and highcharts by default hidden the x-range which doesn't have y values. I did not use the `setExtremes` as I mentioned above after the data was imported. I added that line just after I did my import and now highchart shows the blank space.

Comment: So you are setting wrong extremes, for example wrong day/month? Without seeing this live I can only guess, sorry.

Comment: Please see this  [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/67ewJ/1/) . If I don't apply the `setExtremes`, my xAxis won't start from 1.

Comment: I am setting `setExtremes` correctly but not after the chart is drawn. After the chart is drawn, I added the line and issue is resolved.

Comment: Have you tried to set min and max this way: http://jsfiddle.net/67ewJ/2/ ? Also you can add null values for missing points (1, 2, 3).

Comment: The chart initially is blank. When the user clicks a button, I add the data for the last 7 days to the chart hence min and max is not fixed (xAxis is UTC time). User can add the data for any given time range. The xAxis values are not at a fixed interval so I don't want to modify the data just to add null values. I think `setExtremes` works fine.

Comment: @lostpacket Apparently, there's no issue here, since `setExtremes` works fine, then.